# complex result in numerical integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm in a contradiction that I open the topic is here because it is also related to programming. I try to calculate definite integral using [Simpson's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html). However, after some tries, I have encountered a problem referred as `nan` meaning `not a number`. How can I know ? I checked some equations. I get that my program shows nan when result of the equation is complex number. The interesting point is that I discussed the result with my lecturer, he said if you find complex number from numerical integral calculation I will give you two prizes(no pun intended). At the first glance, I acknowledged him to be right. However, I found complex number. How is it possible? For example, when I try to calculate $$ \sin^{t}(2t) + \cos^{t}(\frac{t}{9})  = pow(sin(2*t), t ) + pow( cos(t / 9), t ) $$

```
.
.
29)  1.066912
30)  pow(sin(2*1.525000), 1.525000 ) + pow( cos(1.525000 / 9), 1.525000 )
30)  1.004298
31)  pow(sin(2*1.575000), 1.575000 ) + pow( cos(1.575000 / 9), 1.575000 )
31)  nan
32)  pow(sin(2*1.625000), 1.625000 ) + pow( cos(1.625000 / 9), 1.625000 )
32)  nan
.
.
.
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the $()^t$. E. g. by definition $\sin(2t)^t = \exp(x\log(\sin(x)))$. But evaluating the logarithm (principal value) at negative number gives a complex result. $\log(-|x|)= \log(|x|)\pm i\pi$ (depending on the definition) for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. That is why it is perfectly fine to get a complex answer. Even if it doesn't look like it at first.

Comment: I agree that a problem could come from the determination one takes of the (complex) logarithm. But in the examples that are given, this problem occurs only when there is **coupling** between the argument and an exponent. Like in my example where: $Cos[2.629]^{2.629}$ is given by Mathematica the value $-0.27461 + 0.640097 i$. I believe there is another explanation.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an anwer but an enlargement.

I was at first incredulous.

I tried a routine calculation with Mathematica, which is known to be rigorous in its treatment of real vs. complex numbers, and I was very surprised to find a similar (even slightly worse) situation.

Mathematica (an old version), at the request :

Cos[2.629]^2.629 gives the result : -0.27461 + 0.640097 I  !

Sin[2*(2.477)]^(2.477)  gives 0.06711 + 0.92716*I ...

and the same result if you separate the computation into 2 steps...

a=Sin[2*(2.477)] ; a^(2.477)

Of course, we know that the trigonometric functions can take complex values, but for complex arguments ! Why this behaviour ? It's valuable to ask it in a numerical analysis forum...

Comment: I look strange that a downvote is given. Could it be explained ? I think I have tried to bring something to the issue, even if it is not, of course, a solution as I have said in the first sentence ; it could hardly fit anyway in a simple comment.